# Vb.Net 2019 Windows Forms Application Can't Connect to Openoffice in form load event

Tags: vb.net, openoffice-calc

Problem 1 Entering the OpenOffice URI connection string "file://....."
When I type the second forward slash the string characters turn from the standard red to blue. The basic content of the error message is "Represents text as sequence of UTF 16 token units. I haven't a clue what this means. But more important; since when is a string not a string?

Problem 2 Alternate approach using the following code

```
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim Url
    Dim Dummy(1) As Object
    Dim oDesk As Object
    Dim osm = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")

    oDesk = osm.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
    Url = New Uri("S:\Water Data.ods") 
    oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL(Url, "_blank", 0, Dummy)
```

here every thing seems to goes well until loading of the component oDoc then I get "can't convert the value of vartype 13 to the expected UNO type of class 12

Comment: Programming OpenOffice in vb.net is quite courageous, the [docs](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/CLI/CLI_Language_Binding) are both useless and outdated.  I *think* the exception message is trying to tell you that it only knows com.sun.star.uno types.  So doesn't understand System.Uri, try a string instead.

Comment: See https://www.connectionstrings.com/openoffice-spreadsheet/ which will refer you to a user's forum.

Comment: Mary thanks for reference. Unfortunately, it is for C#. Just tried in VB.net and no such object.

Comment: Hans You have not read my question. Problem 1 vb.net will not allow me to enter the described string??? Does vb.net handle "//" as some kind of token/delimiter?. In any event, I can't use a string. The URI returns a properly formatted string but gives me the cited error message.

Comment: I think it is very important to note that ludicrous statements like "docs are useless" should be avoided. Openoffice includes spreadsheet "calc" files. If we were talking about taking a dog for a walk then, of course, a spreadsheet is of no use. If I'm running an experiment and have 5000 data points saved to a "csv" file, I can import the data into Excel, do a full statistical data analysis, and plot the data in about 15 minutes-- maybe 30 if I take a long coffee break. Clearly not useless. Young people get the wrong impression